# Address already in use issue when running rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Hi all I am new to rails and I am facing issue with running the rails app in WSL. I generated a new rails project and just set it up for deployment using capistrano. The deployment was successful. However, now I cant run rails locally. `rails s` gives me error.

I am posting the log here

[image: log]

I tried checking the port to see if any process was using port 3000 but it showed nothing. The commands that I tried are
lsof -wni tcp:3000
ps aux | grep puma

but they show no process that I can kill. I dont think this is an issue with WSL because I can run another newly created rails app.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I used to get this error too. I then realised that after I deleted the `server.pid` file found in either:

> `management\tmp\pids` or > `gateway\tmp\pids`

and restarted the service, it ended up working.

I recommend you make a local copy of the file(s) in the pid folder incase you need it, then delete it, restart your service and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but somehow i had to comment out a line 'activate_control_app' from config/puma.rb to get the app running in local.